# MySQL collation_server breaks special characters

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, collation

we recently ran into an issue that we couldn't explain ourselves.

We use a MySQL 8.0.21 database that our JVM based backend connects to (via JDBC).

Some of these columns are used to compare texts. These are set to the charset `utf8mb4` and collate `utf8mb4_0900_as_ci`. We want them to be case insensitive here.
However, all other columns (non user generated data) are supposed to be set to the collate `utf8mb4_0900_as_cs`, so that e.g. our generated IDs (which contain lower and uppercase letters) can be compared on a case sensitive basis.

During our most recent database migration, we noticed that the `collation_server` is still set to `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`. This is the default our cloud provider has set. Because this isn't the safe default we want it to be, we changed it to `ut8mb4_0900_as_cs`. Given that the collations are explicitly set on all tables, we did not imagine this to be an issue, because the documentation states:

> The server character set and collation are used as default values if the database character set and collation are not specified in CREATE DATABASE statements. They have no other purpose.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-server.html

We expected special characters like ü,ä,ö and emojis to work. However, changing this one variable `collation_server` breaks that functionality.
We always thought the collation isn't responsible for actually formatting the data that is being read and written. Also, our expectation was that these collates are interoperable, given they are both based on `utf8mb4`.

**Tl;dr:** We changed the `collation_server` MySQL variable from `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` to `utf8mb4_0900_as_cs`. This breaks reading & saving of any emojis or special characters inside the db.

**The actual question:** Why does this happen? How does the collate influence how special characters are read from or written into the db?

Comment: I think only the creation/modification of the indexes is affected when the collation changes. (see: [Changes to how MySQL handles data types or character sets. For example, an error in a collation might have been corrected, necessitating a table rebuild to update the indexes for character columns that use the collation.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/rebuilding-tables.html)

Comment: "We expected special characters like ü,ä,ö and emojis to work." -- Show us the specific SQL where they "did not work" and say both what happened and what you wanted.